# How do I make a scoreboard command that shows all players health in bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im trying to make a minigame that is multiplayer and you can see how low on health a player is and throw a splash potion of healing on them to heal them.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Dannk. Unfortunately, your question probably wont get too many answers the way it stands. With questions like yours, we like to see some effort put in by the asker. Just asking, how do I do this, or what command do I use without any supporting evidence of what you tries usually just results in downvotes. So I would I look up some guides and tutorials on minecraft commands and play around with it and if you still need help, come back with what you tried and maybe someone can lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. [Scoreboards](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria) in BE can only have a `dummy` criterion, unlike Java Edition which can have a `health` one.

I can't think of any other way to have a scoreboard of a player's health in  BE.